# Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException... an associon ..to unmapped class- Many toMany

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have auto generated the code using netbeans to create a Hibernate configuration; so I have  two tables mapped like this (Many-to-Many) :

```
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true">
<class name="com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Roles" table="roles"   catalog="jobprograms">
    <id name="rolesName" type="string">
        <column name="roles_name" length="20" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <set name="userses" table="users_roles" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="role_name" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Users">
            <column name="user_name" length="15" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
</class>
```

```
 <hibernate-mapping  auto-import="true">
<class name="com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Users" table="users" catalog="jobprograms">
    <id name="idusers" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="idusers" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="userName" type="string">
        <column name="user_name" length="15" not-null="true" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="userPass" type="string">
        <column name="user_pass" length="15" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="first_name" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="last_name" length="25" />
    </property>
    <set name="roleses" table="users_roles" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="user_name" length="15" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Roles">
            <column name="role_name" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
    <set name="jobprograms" table="jobprogram" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="users_idusers" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Jobprogram" />
    </set>
</class>
```

I have made some modification as you can see above (auto-import=true, lazy=false), cause i have the error message

```
rg.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table users_roles refers to an unmapped class: com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Roles
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1824)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1756)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
```

The config file is

```
<hibernate-configuration>
```

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobprograms?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
    jobprograms_ad
    xxxxx
    thread
    true
    org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
    true
    
    
    
  

the classes have refernce like this :

```
'@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="roleses")
public Set<Users> getUserses() {
    return this.userses;
} '
```

`@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="users_roles", catalog="jobprograms", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name="user_name", nullable=false, updatable=false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name="role_name", nullable=false, updatable=false) })
    public Set<Roles> getRoleses() {
        return this.roleses;
    }`

wHEN RUNNING I HAVE THE ERROR org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException, and in fact the entiti is loaded, but the set<> not..,
When testing the error is 
org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table users_roles refers to an unmapped class: com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Roles, and the HSQL ar not executed.

I tried to look in others post but i couldn't find an answer. Can anybody help me?

In config file the entities are all declared;
I think yhe promlem is in the mapping :

```
e <set name="roleses" table="users_roles" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" >
        <key >
            <column name="user_name" length="15" not-null="true"  />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="test.Roles" property-ref="rolesName">
            <column name="role_name" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
    <set name="jobprograms" table="jobprogram" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="users_idusers" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="test.Jobprogram" />
    </set>
```

and

```
enter  <class name="test.Roles" table="roles" catalog="jobprograms">
    <id name="rolesName" type="string">
        <column name="roles_name" length="20" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <set name="userses" table="users_roles" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key property-ref="rolesName">
            <column name="role_name" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="test.Users" property-ref="userName">
            <column name="user_name" length="15" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
</class>
```

....

Answer (score 0):

this error
    org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table users_roles refers to an         unmapped class: com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Roles

comes when hibernate configuration dont know about entity(Roles) mapping , either you have missed introducing enitity Roles to the hibernate configuration or you have not used correct name , please check configuraiton file and included com.antoiovi.jobprograms.entity.Roles as resourse

Answer (score 0):

I think to have resolved the problem. Actually the proble are unmapped entities. But this happens because the database is not 'well formed'. Indeed the database ha 3 table users, users_roles, roles; the table roles has only one column as primarykey (varchar),and the table user_roles refers to it from its column user_roles;   when forword enginering the ide (in the case netbeans) creates only 2 entities: 'Users', and 'Roles';   So i have re-designed the schema putting some virtual primary key, and creating unique constaint instead. Now i have 3 entities : Users,UserRoles, and Roles.